# Resources for drawable-xlarge-mdpi AND drawable-sw600dp-mdpi without duplication

Tags: android

I want to provide the same image resources/drawables to both drawable-xlarge-mdpi AND drawable-sw600dp-mdpi.

It seems the only way I can do this is by creating two folders under res/ and copying the same set of resources into each folder.

With layouts we can do aliasing.  I.e. creating a file called layout.xml in the values folder with specific qualifiers and adding items to point to a single layout file for both qualifiers:

- values-xlarge\values.xml
- values-sw600dp\values.xml

The contents of both files would be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="activity_shows" type="layout">@layout/activity_shows_tablet</item>
</resources>
```

(Devices matching xlarge or devices matching sw600dp would now use activity_shows_tablet.xml as the layout file for "activity_shows")

Is there a similar approach for drawables?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is there a similar approach for drawables?

It should work exactly as it does for layouts

put `png` resources into the default folder

```
res/drawable/largescreen.png
res/drawable/smallscreen.png
```

create `.xml` resources that refer to the `png`s

```
res/drawable/image.xml
res/drawable-xlarge-mdpi/image.xml
res/drawable-sw600dp-mdpi/image.xml
```

where `image.xml` is something like ([documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#bitmap-element))

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/largescreen" />
```

and then use the XML resource as you would use the png directly

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/image" />
```