# How to handle images in low density large screens in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-image, android-screen-support

I'm writing an Android app and have read up everything I can find on fragmentation and handling multiple screens, particularly from the official Android documentation.

I understand different screen densities utilize the various folders (mdpi, hdpi etc.) for images of varying sizes, and different screen sizes can utilize different layouts by defining them in res/layout-sw600dp layout-sw720dp etc. which all makes sense.

However, when developing my app my primary test device was a HTC Desire X phone 400x800 with 240dpi density and all looks well. I then tested it on a Prestigio Multipad 8.0 tablet and this is where I'm getting confused. The tablet has a screen size of 786x1232 BUT the screen density is only 160dpi. Owing to the fact that the screen density on the tablet is smaller, Android therefore uses the images in the mdpi folder for the tablet, and the slightly bigger ones in the hdpi folder for the phone! This therefore results in images way too small on the tablet.
I don't need to edit the layout for the tablet so the sw720dpi folders aren't a help.
What am I missing or not understanding properly here? How can I make my images scale up for the bigger, lower density tablet screen?

OK, I figured this out eventually. My mistake was I didn't realize drawables work exactly the same as layouts in that I could have a drawable-sw720dp folder which Android fetches the images from in the case of a screen with at least 720pixels of width. For completeness in the scenario I described I could have a drawable-sw720dp-mdpi folder in which to store my images.

I had an additional issue then whereby I had 2 copies of the same image in different drawable folders but I discovered you can reference images using an alias just like layouts. Details of how to do that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418926/resources-for-drawable-xlarge-mdpi-and-drawable-sw600dp-mdpi-without-duplication).

Comment: can you provide some screenshots & relevant code?

Comment: I figured it out petey and added the solution above, but thanks anyway.